# The relation $R = \{(a, b) | a = - b \}$ on the set of integers transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Why is the relation $R = \{(a, b) | a = - b \}$ on the set of integers transitive? My reasoning:
If we consider $(1, -1)$ in the set, then this means that $a = 1$ and $b = -1$. Thus, $1 = -(-1).$ If the set is transitive,
$$
(a = -b) \land (b = - c) \Rightarrow (a = -c).
$$
But I don't understand how this can be if
$$
(1 = -(-1)) \land (-1 = -(1)) \nRightarrow (1=-(1)).
$$
Why is this incorrect? I apologize if this is terribly obvious, but I just can't see it.

Comment: You proved the relation is not transitive.

Comment: It would be transitive if it were $\{(a,b)\mid a=\pm b\}$.

Comment: @KyleMiller I see why transitivity would hold for $a = b$. But wouldn't the reasoning from above apply when we take into consideration $a = -b$?

Comment: @KyleMiller Nevermind, I see why now. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @jjagmath Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The $=$ signs in your display equations should be $R$s.  You have correctly observed that transitivity requires
$$(1R-1) \wedge (-1R1) \implies (1R1)$$
but $1R-1, -1R1, 1 \not R 1$, so the relation is not transitive.

Comment: Okay, I'll take note of this. Thanks a lot.